# 3D line hits a 3D point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a function wich knows if a line hits a point. Is there any function like that? I also want to set the size of my 3D-points in centimetre and dont know how to do that.

I appreciate your help.

For example:
[image]

Assuming that the points have an radius and the lines wouldnt hit the point exact in the middle, is the a function that shows me if a line hit the point?

Comment: Oh man, that's tough (in general). I'm curious to know as well!

Comment: how your line and a sphere represented? Why do you use `matplotlib` tag?

Comment: I think what you actually want to compute is the distance between point and line in 3d see: [Point-Line Distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) and when the distance is smaller than the radius of the sphere around your point, you have a match.

Comment: Surely if you know the equation of the line (a*x + b*y + c*z = 0) you can substitute the values for a, b and c (coordinates of the point) then check that -d < a*x + b*y + c*z < d where d is the diameter of the points. Or am I missing the points?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have classical solution that work in any dimensions.

First of all, you got sphere and a line, and you need to have good model of them. 
Sphere is easy you just have a Vector `.center` and `.diameter`.

```
class Sphere:
    def __init__( sphere, center, diameter ):
       sphere.center=Vector(center)
       sphere.diameter=float(diameter)
```

Line could be more problematic for beginners because it could be defined in many ways.
The most useful comes from parametric equation, you have a direction in Vector `.direction` and some staring point `.center`. We assume that `.direction` is unit length, and `.center` is the nearest point on line from (0,0). In most cases we need to create a line, having to points Vectors:

```
def line_on_two_points( A, B ):
    return Line( direction= Vector(B)-A, center=A )
```

So we have to fix the `direction` and `center` in the constructor. `.direction` is easy to fix wee need just to make it unit length. To find `.center`, we need [scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection). Here is as vector to D:
[image: The nearest point on line from (0,0)]

Having `.direction` as unit length A to B and `center` as from C to A, we could init our line as:

```
class Line:
   def __init__( line, direction, center ):
        line.direction= Vector(direction) / length(direction)
        line.center= center - line.direction*dot(center,line.direction)
```

If we don't have a line, just two points we could just do:

```
#class Sphere:
def colide_line_on_two_points( sphere, A, B ):
    line=line_on_two_points( A-sphere.center, B-sphere.center)
    return length(line.center) < sphere.diameter
```

But when we have a line we try to optimize it as:

```
#class Sphere:
def colide_line( sphere, line ):
    return line.distance_to(sphere.center) < sphere.diameter
```

The `.distance_to()` function is a bit tricky:

[image: Vector from line to point]

```
#class Line:

   def vector_to( line, P ):
       return line.center + line.direction * dot(line.direction,P) - P

   def distance_to( line, P ):
       return length( line.center + line.direction * dot(line.direction,P) - P )

   def move_to( line, P ):
       line.center += line.direction * dot(line.direction,P) - P
```

The last but not least is the `Vector` type, I try numpy, but it's rather slow for 2D,3D:

```
from numpy import array as Vector
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm as length
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an algorithm to find intersections between a line and a sphere. This is a problem commonly found in graphics programming, and there are a lot of articles that probably explain it a lot better than I could. There is one at http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/maths/ray-sphere-intersection/

The basic idea is that you project the sphere onto the line, and then solve the resulting right triangle , formed by the point of intersection, the sphere's center, and the projected point, using the Pythagorean theorem.

Here is the code I used in my pathtracing renderer:

```
hitdata intersectwith(Sphere sphere)
{
    d3Vector projected;

    float t = V.dot(sphere.pos.subtract(O));
    projected = V.normalize().scalarmultiply(t); //the projected vector
    float distnce = (projected.subtract(sphere.pos.subtract(O))).magnitude();
    //the length between the center of your sphere and the projected point
    hitdata outdata; // a class containing the results of the intersection
    outdata.hit = false;
    outdata.t = 110;
    if(t<=0)
    {
        return outdata;
    }
    if(distnce<sphere.r)
    {// the line is less distant from the center of the sphere than the surface
        outdata.hit = true;
        float deltaT = sqrtf((sphere.r*sphere.r)-(distnce*distnce));//Pythagorean theorem
        outdata.coord = O.add(V.scalarmultiply(t-deltaT));
        //calculating intersection coordinates
        outdata.normal = outdata.coord.subtract(sphere.pos);
        outdata.normal = outdata.normal.normalize();//calculating surface normals
        outdata.material = sphere.material;
        outdata.t = t-deltaT;
    }
    return outdata;
}
```